# Private Chat with Parse and MessagesViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, chat, message

I'm making a private chat with Parse and the framework MessageViewController.
I succeed to display all messages' conversation from User A to User B, but I can't differentiate who is the sender or the receiver with bubble.
In parse I've a class "Chat" with columns : "objectId", "DestinateurId" (receiver), "senderId" (sender), "text", "createdAt". When I send a message, that completes well the database.
I just want that when User A sends a message to User B, we see that User A uses BubbleMessageStyleOutgoing and User B will receive BubbleMessageStyleIncoming. (At the moment, every messages are in BubbleMessageStyleOutgoing)

So firstly, I make a query for getting messages from sender, and receiver. With that I'm getting all message I need to display.
question : I can't access to value NSArray *messages out from viewDidLoad, so how can I differentiate this message is from sender or receiver ? (because I need to differentiate in other method (- (BubbleMessageStyle)messageStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath )

Here is my code :

ChatViewController.h:

```
#import "MessagesViewController.h"

@interface ChatViewController : MessagesViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *messages;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *destinateurChat;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *senderMsg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *destinateurMsg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *msg;
@end
```

ChatViewController.m:

```
#import "ChatViewController.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "SVProgressHUD.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@interface ChatViewController ()

@end
id message;
NSDate *receiveDate;
NSString *text;
@implementation ChatViewController

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Messages";
    PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"];
    [query1 whereKey:@"DestinateurId" equalTo:self.destinateurChat];
    [query1 whereKey:@"senderId" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    //[query1 orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"];
    [query2 whereKey:@"DestinateurId" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query2 whereKey:@"senderId" equalTo:self.destinateurChat];
    //[query2 orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        PFQuery *orQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1, query2]];
        [orQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
        [orQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *messages, NSError *error) {
            // Do real error handling in your app...
self.msg = messages;
            for (PFObject *message in messages) {
                if ([message[@"senderId"] isEqualToString:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]]) {
                    // This is an outgoing message
                    self.senderMsg = [messages valueForKey:@"text"];
                    self.messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    [self.messages addObjectsFromArray:self.senderMsg];
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                } else {
                    // This is an incoming message
                    self.destinateurMsg = [messages valueForKey:@"text"];
                    [self.messages addObjectsFromArray:self.destinateurMsg];
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                }
            }
        }];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });


    NSLog(@"%@", self.senderMsg);
NSLog(@"%@", self.msg);
    UIButton *exitButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [exitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backToInboxView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [exitButton setTitle:@"Inbox" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    exitButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 60, 60);
    [self.view addSubview:exitButton];
   }

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.messages.count;
}

#pragma mark - Messages view controller
- (BubbleMessageStyle)messageStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.destinateurMsg ? BubbleMessageStyleIncoming : BubbleMessageStyleOutgoing;
}


- (NSString *)textForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (void)sendPressed:(UIButton *)sender withText:text
{
    [self.messages addObject:text];
    if((self.messages.count - 1) % 2)
        [MessageSoundEffect playMessageSentSound];
    else
        [MessageSoundEffect playMessageReceivedSound];
    [self finishSend];
    PFObject *chat = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Chat"];
    [chat setObject:self.destinateurChat forKey:@"DestinateurId"];
    [chat setObject:text forKey:@"text"];
    [chat setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"senderId"];

    [chat saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An error occurred!"
                                                                message:@"Please try sending your message again."
                                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            [alertView show];
        }
        else {
            // Everything was successful!
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)backToInboxView{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

I shall be very glad to follow your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing an "or" query.

Here is Parse's sample code on this topic:

```
PFQuery *lotsOfWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[lotsOfWins whereKey:@"wins" greaterThan:@150];

PFQuery *fewWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[fewWins whereKey:@"wins" lessThan:@5];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[fewWins,lotsOfWins]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    // results contains players with lots of wins or only a few wins.
}];
```

For you, this would appear to look like this:

```
PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"];
[query1 whereKey:@"DestinateurId" equalTo:self.destinateurChat];
[query1 whereKey:@"senderId" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];

PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Chat"];
[query2 whereKey:@"DestinateurId" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
[query2 whereKey:@"senderId" equalTo:self.destinateurChat];

PFQuery *orQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1, query2]];
[orQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *messages, NSError *error) {
    // Do real error handling in your app...
    for (PFObject *message in messages) {
        if ([message[@"senderId"] isEqualToString:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]]) {
            // This is an outgoing message

        } else {
            // This is an incoming message

        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Alright, I'm happy to discover that ! So now, I can know if it's an incoming or outgoing message, but how to access to this information out of viewDidLoad ? Because the final purpose is to implement that in "(BubbleMessageStyle)messageStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" method

Comment: @Viny76 I typically set up a data loading method pathway and show a "Please wait..." dialog while the query is executing, then, when the data comes in, I assign the data to a local property and call `reloadData` on my `UITableView`. Check out `MBProgressHUD` (free on github) for showing the "Please wait..." dialog in a really nice way.

Comment: I've updated my code, that's ok, I reloadData, but when you say : "I assign the data to a local property", can you use this property out from viewDidLoad ?
I've to use it in messageStyleForRowAtIndexPath. I'm sorry if I don't understand that.
(PS : thank you for your help!), and I know MBProgreesHUD :)

Comment: @Viny76 Sure. I make a property on the `UIViewController`, say `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *messages;`. Then, I assign the query's results to this property when the query returns. Then, when you ask the `UITableView` (or whatever is displaying your messages) to reload, it will call the data source protocol methods. In **those** methods, (where you should be given an `indexPath`), you access the message for that `indexPath` and determine message type based on the object's `senderId`.

Comment: EDIT : MBHudProgress is implemented.
I'm sorry but I don't understand. For example, I've made a property for senderMsg and destinateurMsg (where I stock my messages). But if I NSLog their properties (after reload), out from query, that NSLog null (look in my code with NSLog(@"%@", self.senderMsg); --> returning null.
How use it in indexPath for example in my case ? :$

Comment: And I've tried with another property (msg) --> edited in my code. NSLog(@"%@", self.msg) returns will too... :(
I really need this help...

Comment: @Viny76 I really wish we could take this to chat, so I'm going to try to post a couple of comments to get us there. The solution to your problem that I'm proposing requires a rather thorough re-writing of your view controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68373/discussion-between-mbm29414-and-viny76).